# if-statement difficulty with multiple ifelse

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm doing something simple wrong here.  Can anyone help quickly?

```
    <?php 
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;                  
    $Property_Type = get_post_meta($postid, 'Property_Type', true);
    if ($Property_Type == 'Residential') { ?>
     Single Family

      <?php 
       elseif ($Property_Type == 'Business Opportunity') { ?>
        Biz Opp  <?php }

           else { ?>   

          <?php echo c2c_get_custom('Property_Type'); ?>

   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You are missing '}' on the line 7, before elseif.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong but the below works

```
    <?php 
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;                  
    $Property_Type = get_post_meta($postid, 'Property_Type', true);
    if ($Property_Type == 'Residential') { ?>

    Single Family  

<?php } elseif ($Property_Type == 'Business Opportunity') { ?>

    Biz Opp
```

```
    <?php echo c2c_get_custom('Property_Type'); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I see now.. I was missing a }